# Create Pandas Pivot Table without loosing any column

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have this dataset

[image]

And I want to have a sort of pivoting with the subtotals calculation.

So that I used the pandas pivot_table function:

```
pivot1 = pd.pivot_table(df, index=('Company Code', 'Company Code Text', 'Partner Company Code', 'BKA Item', 'Subitem', 'BKA SubItem Text') , values='Amount')
pivot1
```

The calculation is correct but my output is reduced to one column:

[image]

How could I keep in my output the same columns with the same aggregation?

Comment: try `.reset_index()` at the end of the pivot code?

Answer (score 0):

Since most of the columns become index columns, you can change them into normal columns through this:

```
pivot1.reset_index()
```